# How can I check the status of an asterisk trunk

Tags: asterisk

So if I type `sip show peers` I get back a table telling me that the status of the trunks is "OK", but I don't think it tests to see if authentication has worked. Is there a way of testing if the trunk is OK and calls can go through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for different text strings like `BUSY`,`CONGESTION`,`CHANUNAVAIL`,etc from checking the `${DIALSTATUS}` variable in your dialplan. 
You could've a log which is created with the hangup cause after a channel is hungup.

Comment: Hmm sorry but I'm a bit new to asterisk.

It looks like I need to put something in [outgoing] so that when any outgoing calls have finished the dial status and trunk name will be put in a file somewhere to be viewed or if dial status is chanunavail something happens which can trigger a script which I'll make later. 

Can you help me further or point me to where I can find how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: at the start of ur dialplan write your variable ${DIALSTATUS} to another variable using Set(var = ${DIALSTATUS}) and then finally use the hangup extension to invoke a script/system command which dumps it on to a file.. exten => h,1,System(..) at the end of ur context..